# Search inside site collection

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

I very new in Sharepoint and i want to configure the search of my page of sharepoint 2013.

I want to show only items or documents inside my site collection.
I would really appreciate something like step by step proces because i dont have too much experience working on sharepoint.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The key word to search on is [Result Source](https://www.google.com/search?q=sharepoint%202013%20result%20scope&oq=sharepoint%202013%20result%20scope&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l2.5306j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=sharepoint%202013%20result%20source%20site%20collection). This article will help you set one up http://www.techmikael.com/2013/04/limiting-search-results-in-sharepoint.html. Welcome to the fun world of SharePoint.